# Why is N not valid as variable in ParametricPlot?

Tags: plotting, crash, variable, system-variables

Why is

```
ParametricPlot[{Log[N!], Log[Sqrt[2 Pi N] E^-N N^N]}, {N, 1, 10}]
```

not working when

```
ListPlot[Table[{Log[N!], Log[Sqrt[2 Pi N] E^-N N^N]}, {N, 1, 100}]]
```

is working?

Comment: N is the name of a function i.e. it is a protected symbol,
`N[expr] gives the numerical value of expr. 

N[expr,n] attempts to give a result with n-digit precision.  `

Use `?N` or use the help `F1` to find out what symbols mean

OT: how can I flag questions like this as "Simple misunderstanding" and thus close-worthy?

Comment: @AndreasP I believe you need 3000 reputation to access the close votes privilege, see here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: The `ParametricPlot` code causes a **crash** in V11.0.0 (Mac OSX).   No error message.  Maybe not such a simple thing to track down, although everyone needs to know about `N[]`, I suppose.

Comment: @AndreasP Then why is second code working? Why isn't N a protected symbol here?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that N is already defined in Mathematica, N[expression] gives the numerical approximation of expression. Other candidates for similar errors are I, and E. So when Mathematica processes your code, when it excounters your N, Mathematica does not see a variable but a command. This is one of the pitfalls of the Mathematica language. A convenient rule that seasoned users employ is to not create anything in uppercase.

Comment: Is N the only single-lettered  function?

Comment: Then why is second code working? Why doesn't mathematica see N as command this time?

Comment: Other single letter functions are D for derivative, E (the Euler constant, 2.72...), I (the imaginary unit, the square root of -1), O for order. But I suspect that the reason why the second piece of code works is that there Mathematica processes the `Table[ ]` function using local variable definitions, and your local definition of N overrides the global definition, and this does not happen in the first case.

Comment: If you type ?N you get the global definition. If you try to assign something to N you get an error but somehow the `Table` uses a temporary local assignment without triggering an error.